# unable to record mono audio in raspberry pi3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian, audio-recording, alsa, audacity

i've been trying to record audio using re-speaker 2 mic hat on my raspberry pi3 .stereo recording is working fine but .i cant't make mono recording works ,all i got was just white noise.

**recording stereo on audacity**
[image: recording stereo on audacity]
**screen shot of mono recording on audacity** 
[image: Mono recording -not working]

this is my alsa info

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=bfd07e437056c0a9560290340fa9b4c0a5ade7e1

Respeaker 2 mic pi hat - http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker_2_Mics_Pi_HAT/

any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arecord -L 
plughw:CARD=ArrayUAC10,DEV=0
ReSpeaker 4 Mic Array (UAC1.0), USB Audio
Hardware device with all software conversions
arecord  -D plughw:0 -f S16_LE -r 16000 -c 1 audio-1ch-16k.pcm
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because my left channel mic was broken .now i can record in stereo and extract mono using audioop library